# How to deploy standalone jar pointing javaagent to Bluemix CloudFoundry

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, vert.x

I have been developing a small app through Vert.x and especially with Vertx-Sync. 
Vertx-sync allows you to work with asynchronous APIs, but using a direct synchronous style using lightweight threads aka Fibers. To start fiber instrumentation a javaagent option should be passed as a vm argument.  As a example I run my app through:

```
 java -jar vertxTestCF -javaagent:{path-to-the-jar}/quasar-core-0.7.5-jdk8.jar
```

. 
Everything works well on local but I am unable to deploy vertxTestCF on the cloud vi cloudfoundry CLI. I deploy vertxTestCF with following CLI:

```
cf push -f manifest.yml vertxTestCF
```

That is my manifest.yml:

```
    applications:
    - path: ./target/vertxTestCF-1.0-fat.jar
      memory: 256M
      instances: 1
      name: vertxTestCf
      buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#3.x
      env:
          JAVA_OPTS: -javaagent:target/quasar-core-0.7.5-jdk8.jar
```

Error message during deployment is :

```
[APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : target/quasar-core-0.7.5-jdk8.
```

Any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track by using `JAVA_OPTS`, but the path you're setting is wrong.  It's the path on your local machine, however, the code is running on Cloud Foundry which will have a different path.

```
JAVA_OPTS: -javaagent:target/quasar-core-0.7.5-jdk8.jar
```

Based on your manifest.yml, you are pushing this file:

```
 - path: ./target/vertxTestCF-1.0-fat.jar
```

That means the root of your application is going to be the root of this JAR file.  That's essentially what `path` means.  The root of your app on CF will start with the path you specify.

Thus, if you need to reference `quasar-core-0.7.5-jdk8.jar` it would need to be included in `vertxTestCF-1.0-fat.jar` and the relative path to `quasar-core-0.7.5-jdk8.jar` would be the path where you put the file inside `vertxTestCF-1.0-fat.jar`.

Ex:

I have `test-fat.jar`.  Inside it I hav another JAR located at `lib/my-second.jar`.  If I need to reference the second JAR, it would be `-javaagent:lib/my-second.jar`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I added quasar-core-0.7.5-jdk8.jar inside of the jar to be deployed and that actually solved the issue.

Thank you, your comment helps me a lot.